# How to change the scene view in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever I create a new project in Unity 5 I see this

[image]

and I'm not familiar with this scene. The problem is I don't know how to change this scene to this one.

[image]

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that Unity is in 2D Mode. Click the 2D Button that is next to the Game tab in Unity. That will switch you back to 3D Mode. It is circled in red in the picture below.

[image]

And whenever you are creating a new project, make sure to select 3D not 2D and stuff like this won't happen. If it does, click on the 2D button circle in the first image, save scene and exit. That should now be fixed.

[image]